# Why you need to add empty constructors for UIViewController subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Why I need to add these constructors (empty) even if I will not add some custom initialisation things into `UIViewController` subclass?

```
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
```

Comment: Try to avoid the init (in your case it's superfluous) and put everything in `awakeFromNib`. It's a bit annoying with that `required` stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift, unlike some languages, a subclass does not normally inherit its superclass's initializers. Automatic initializer inheritance can only take place under certain conditions. Given a class `A`:

```
class A {
    var a: Int
    var r: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.r = 0
        self.a = a
    }
}
```

A class `B` automatically inherits initializers only if both of the following conditions are met:

a. All newly introduced properties of the subclass are have been assigned default values.

b. No new designated initializers have been introduced into the subclass, or any newly introduced initializers provide their own implementation of superclass initializers:

```
//All values assigned, no additional initializers
class C: A {
    var c: Int = 9
}

//Provides an implementation of class A's initializer
class B: A {
    init() {
        super(a: 0)
    }
}
```

Now if we introduce a required initializer into a class, things get hairy.

```
class AWithRequired {
    var a: Int
    var r: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.r = 0
        self.a = a
    }

    required init(a: Int, r: Int) {
        self.r = r
        self.a = a
    }

}
```

In this case we can't introduce any non-designated initializers without also overriding the required initializer:

```
//Still OK--no new initializers introduced
class BWithRequired: AWithRequired {
    var b: Int = 9
}

//Doesn't ovverride required initializer, throws an error
class CWithRequired: AWithRequired {
    init() {
        super.init(a: 0, r: 0)
    }
}   //ERROR: Required Initializer must be supplied by subclass of 'AWithRequired'

//OK, overrides required initializer
class DWithRequired: AWithRequired {
    required init(a: Int, r: Int) {
        super.init(a: 0, r: 0)
    }
}

//OK, provides non-designated initializer
class EWithRequired: AWithRequired {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(a: 0, r: 0)
    }
}
```

As you can see from the examples, the only way to get around the restriction and still implement a custom initializer is to introduce a non-designated, e.g. `convenience` initializer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, when initializing new variables in your class, you need to assign them.

Example:

```
class yourTestClass
{
     var testString:String = ""
     //or
     var testStringTwo:String = String()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works for a non UIViewController class, but when you subclass it and run it crash

Comment: Thats wierd, can you paste your code? It should work great in a UIViewController subclass aswell..

Comment: That's because I'm creating it with a nib file in one case... It crash saying that the controller don't implement that constructor.